# Difference between account.microsoft.com and myaccount.microsoft.com

Tags: microsoft-account

I wanted to check a BitLocker recovery key. Google Search told me to visit:

> https://**myaccount**.microsoft.com/device-list

Did so and when trying to authenticate I was hit with the message that my email address was not found in their system even though I've been using a Microsoft Account with that email address for the past 20+ years:

[image]

A couple of minutes later I found out that my BitLocker keys are actually here:

> https://**account**.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey

I was again asked to authenticate, but this time my email was found.

What is the difference between ***account**.microsoft.com* and ***myaccount**.microsoft.com*?